# Sonatype Nexus: Where in the GUI can I add a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, nexus

I'm using Sonatype Nexus 2.5.0-04.  I'm trying to add a SSL certificates in the user interface, as described in the documentation here:
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ssl-sect-client-cert.html

The documentation says "The administration interface for SSL certificates as visible in Figure 23.1, 'SSL Certificates Administration' and can be accessed by selecting SSL Certificates in the right hand Administration menu."

Where is the "right hand Administration menu"? I've looked everywhere.  I can't find a link for SSL certificates in the GUI anywhere.  I thought perhaps this might be a feature available only in the professional version, but there is no mention of that in the documentation on the differences between the two versions.

Comment: That's only a pro feature, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature that is only available in Nexus Professional and it should be the left hand navigation.. I will fix this in the book.

Update: Documentation is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to make an appreciation about configuring Nexus front with SSL and a self-signed certificate because when you use the keytool to generate de keystore.jks file as is indicated in https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213465768-SSL-Certificate-Guide?_ga=2.171695904.1899216110.1638870535-818117565.1624006959

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -alias example.com \
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 5000 -keypass password \
-dname 'CN=*.example.com, OU=Sonatype, O=Sonatype, L=Unspecified, ST=Unspecified,  C=US' \
-ext SAN=DNS:nexus.example.com,DNS:clm.example.com,DNS:repo.example.com,DNS:www.example.com'
```

you obtain an *Invalid keystore format* error bacause the default **TrustStoreType** of keytool is **PKCS12**. I had to force it to JKS to be able to start Nexus with the **-storeType** option.

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks -storeType JKS -storepass password -alias example.com \
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 5000 -keypass password \
-dname 'CN=*.example.com, OU=Sonatype, O=Sonatype, L=Unspecified, ST=Unspecified,  C=US' \
-ext SAN=DNS:nexus.example.com,DNS:clm.example.com,DNS:repo.example.com,DNS:www.example.com'
```

I don't know if you could correct it in the documentation or at least to make some appreciation about.

I've found this problem with the Nexus' version **3.30.1.01**.